# How can I check if the input file and output file are in the same format in R

Tags: r, database, datatable

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRt1Q.png)I imported my inputs from a "Table1.txt" file using read.table, then I worked on my table then I would like to save my outputs in a new text file "Table1Modifed.txt" using write.table and keep everything in the same format

I would like to check if the files "Table1.txt" and "TableModified.txt" are exactly in the same format(Number of digits,Uppercase Lower case...)

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? By file format, people usually specify the way information is encoded, e.g. xls, doc or txt. So in that sense, both your files are in the same format by definition.

Comment: Number of digits,Upper case lower case

Comment: Do you mean in the txt file itself (ex. header information), or in the filename?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to compare contents of two files in R, you cause `diffr()` from the `diffr` package. This will point contents that are different. Is this what you are looking for?